# How to stop execution of the code in Testing once an exception is occurred

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm automating a web application using Selenium-web driver. Once the script breaks at any point I want to stop execution of the code instead of continuing with the next method so that I can know where the automation is breaking. Could anyone please help me how can I do that.

Here is the snippet of the catch block(i.e. the exception I'm using now)

```
try {
   //code
} 
catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Exception occurred *** " +e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Why not an `assert(false)` in the catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I would put this in the catch block to help you trace the problem.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(1)
}
```

or alternatively you could put a print statement in each catch block that identifies which block failed.

ie.

```
try{
//make a cake
}
catch(CakeException e)
{
   System.out.println("Failed at cake baking);
}

try{
//make a salad
}
catch(LettuceException e)
{
   System.out.println("Failed at lettuce chopping);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, tests are supposed to be independent by design, so the fail of the one should not affect the others. If you stop the execution on the first failed test , then how do you know how many more errors you have in your code?

That's a kind of a general idea explaining why testng doesn't contain desired feature out of the box. You can, however, still get an advantage of test dependency mechanism provided by testng:

```
@Test
public void serverStartedOk() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
public void method1() {}
```

So you need to chain your methods this way to ensure execution is broken at the first fail.

Answer (score 0):

that is my way control all exeptions.

create method which visible for all classes

```
protected void exeption(String variable){
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("stop test ____ something your code - exeption ______");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Check Variables:  " + variable);
    System.out.println("____________________________________________");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ooppss"));
}

private void testName() {
String variable = "something";
        if(1!=2){
      exeption(variable);
    }
}
```